# Creating Playing Cards

Tags: javascript, object

Having an issue creating objects in JavaScript.

Trying to create a deck of playing cards which I can then display however I want. I am good with the HTML stuff to display them, just having an issue understanding what I am doing wrong in the JavaScript which is only creating undefined cards for me.

```
(function () {

function Card (rank, suit) {

    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;

};

function Deck() {

    this.deck = new Array();

    this.makeDeck = makeDeck;
    this.shuffle = shuffle;
    this.deal = deal;
}
function makeDeck() {

    var ranks = new Array("A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                    "J", "Q", "K");
    var suits = new Array("Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hears", "Spades");

    this.deck = new Array(52);

    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
            this.deck[i*ranks.length + j] = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);
            document.write("Card made \n");
        }
    }
};

function shuffle() {
    var i, n, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < this.deck.length; j++) {
            k = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deck.length);
            temp = this.deck[j];
            this.deck[j] = this.deck[k];
            this.deck[k] = temp;
        }
    }
    document.write("Cards Shuffled");
};



function deal() {

    if (this.deck.length > 0) {
        return this.deck.shift();
    }
    else return null;
};

var deck = new Deck();

deck.makeDeck();
deck.shuffle();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        var Card = new Card(deck.deal);
        var c = JSON.stringify(Card);
        document.write(this.deck[j]);
    }
}


   } ());
```

Comment: 1. Array literal syntax (`['a', 'b']`) is usually preferable to using the `Array` constructor. 2. Look at what you're doing in `makeDecks`. 3. You should use DOM methods such as `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('x'))` rather than `document.write`.

Comment: Not really understanding what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problematic line :

`this.deck = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);`

`this.deck` is supposed to be the array that includes all your cards, but with the above line, you're overriding it everytime with the single new card.

### You have 2 options :

#### First option

Instead of `this.deck = new Array(52)`, use `this.deck = []` instead, initializing an empty array to this.deck.

Then use `this.deck.push(new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]))` to push all the combinations of the cards to your deck.

#### Second option

The problem with the first option is that `array.push` is not really efficient. Read [this](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/10/15/javascript-array-performance.html) for more info. It wouldn't really matter for a 52-sized array, just putting this on the table for everyone's info.

Alternatively, you could use `this.deck[i] = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i])` to populate your array. You could use `this.deck = []` or `this.deck = new Array(52)` for this. Either would work.

Comment: Actually this answer doesn't count anymore. I see that you've edited your question and you've addressed the issue. I'm posting another answer because I saw another problem.

Comment: Any luck with that other problem?

Comment: Check my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your "main" execution part :

```
var deck = new Deck();

deck.makeDeck();
deck.shuffle();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        var Card = new Card(deck.deal);
        var c = JSON.stringify(Card);
        document.write(this.deck[j]);
    }
}
```

There are several things worth noting.

1. Change `var Card` from `var Card = new Card(deck.deal);`, as the variable `Card` overrides the function `Card` after the first iteration.
2. `deck.deal` is a function. What you need is `deck.deal`'s return value, therefore, you must use `deck.deal()`
3. `document.write(this.deck[j]);` - You should use `deck.deck[j]` instead, because what you need to access is the deck you initialized in `var deck`, and to access the **actual deck of cards**, you need to access the **deck property** of the object deck. Therefore, you need to use `deck.deck[j]`

Comment: Ok, made the changes you said. Makes perfect sense so thank you. deck.deck[j] just drops off an [object Object] (8 times). I really appreciate your help if you know where to go from there.

Comment: That's because you're printing it directly using `document.write`. HTML can't understand objects, JavaScript does. If you need to see the ranks and suits, get the values from `deck.deck[j]`. Try printing `deck.deck[j].rank` and `deck.deck[j].suit`.

Comment: Ok, sorry I was getting around to that. Yea those `deck.deck[j].suit` did not seem to output any values.

Comment: Wondering why you posted multiple answers.. farming rep asking to upvote each of them..?!

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in JS but one thing that rings to me is in your for cycle the deck assignment `this.deck = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);` shouldn't it also be indexed as you create the cards as in:

```
for (i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
            this.deck[ranks.length*i+j] = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);
        }
    }
```

Probably that is why you do not have the deck you wished to form